# MySQL - Create a view with manual cross join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view with cross join based on multiple if conditions.

I know which column to join with which columns.

> 1 in Table A with 1 & 2 in Table B,
>
> 2 in Table A with 1 & 3 in Table B.

I can do the same by creating a mapping table with this logic and use that for joining, but can it be done in the view definition itself, i.e. logic is in the view definition?

Table A

```
ID | Animal
1  | Man
2  | Panda
```

Table B

```
ID | Fruit
1  | Bananna
2  | Apple
3  | Bamboo
```

I want to have view as per known conditions expected would be like

View

```
Man   | Bananna
Man   | Apple
Panda | Bananna
Panda | Bamboo
```

Comment: What is `known conditions` ?

Comment: Like I know `1` ID in Table A needs to be crossed with `1` and `2` in Table B

Comment: How do you know that? Is that logic stored anywhere? It sounds like you need a junction table to store this e.g. `CREATE TABLE ABMapping (AID INT, BID INT); INSERT INT ABMapping (AID, BID) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3);`, then you can use this junction table to join your two known tables.

Comment: I want to store the logic in the view definition itself. I do have an option to create a new mapping table with these ID mapping and use that for joining. But I want to do in the view creation syntax itself.

Comment: @YogeshSharma added the conditions in the question.

Comment: @garg10may  The reason to store it in a table is if it changes you can control it though data instead of a code change.  This gives greater flexibility to your end user and requires fewer code changes by developers.

Comment: hmm, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select *
from a cross join
     b
where (a.id, b.id) in ( (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3) );
```

I'm not sure if you are looking for a more concise way to write this.

Comment: nice and concise though I created a junction table which is better, I was looking for this where condition.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do this: create a derived table using your known values and simply join to it as your junction/associative table.  Though I would store this in a table instead for greater flexibility and ease of maintenance long term.

Note: This approach eliminates the need for a cross join.  You could do a cross join and exclude those record that are in a different set

```
SELECT A.Animal, B.Fruit
FROM A
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 as Animal_ID,1  as Fruit_ID UNION ALL 
            SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2,3) Derived
 on A.ID = Derived Animal_ID
INNER JOIN B 
 on Derived.Fruit_ID = B.ID
```

If you have to keep the cross join (poor performance on large tables) then this may work...

```
SELECT A.Animal B.Fruit
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM (SELECT 1 as Animal_ID,1  as Fruit_ID UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 2,3) Derived
                  WHERE A.ID = Derived.Animal_ID
                   and  B.ID = Derived.Fruit_ID)
```

However you might be better off storing the quantities that don't match depending on table volumes over time.

Both of these approaches HARD CODE values.  That's generally the first sign as a developer you're doing something wrong.  In very rare circumstances should values be hard coded; instead store them as variables in a table which allows for flexibility of change with out code changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;

CREATE TABLE A
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,Animal VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES
(1,'Man'),
(2,'Panda');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;

CREATE TABLE B
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,Fruit VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO b VALUES
(1,'Banana'),
(2,'Apple'),
(3,'Bamboo');

SELECT * 
  FROM a 
  JOIN b 
    ON (a.id = 1 AND b.id IN(1,2)) 
    OR (a.id = 2 AND b.id IN(1,3));
+----+--------+----+--------+
| ID | Animal | ID | Fruit  |
+----+--------+----+--------+
|  1 | Man    |  1 | Banana |
|  2 | Panda  |  1 | Banana |
|  1 | Man    |  2 | Apple  |
|  2 | Panda  |  3 | Bamboo |
+----+--------+----+--------+
```

Note that views serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL.

Comment: didn't get you? Views serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL?

Comment: You mean this syntax of `JOIN ON` won't work in MySql or in general `Views` in MySql are not useful?

Comment: I mean that in general, views in MySQL are not useful.

Comment: Can you refer me to some article/book/post, I have been seeing views all my life. I understand stored procedures, MVs could be better in some scenario but than it's for all by specifically MySql.

Answer (score 1):

You can hard code your mapping into the view, using something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW BadWay
AS
SELECT map.AID, a.Name AS AName, map.BID, b.Name AS BName
FROM TableA AS a
     INNER JOIN
     (   SELECT 1 AS AID, 1 AS BID UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS AID, 2 AS BID UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS AID, 1 AS BID UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS AID, 3 AS BID
     ) AS map
        ON map.AID = a.ID
     INNER JOIN TableB AS b
        ON b.ID = map.BID;
```

I would *highly* recommend that you don't though. If and when you want to add, edit or delete mappings, it is much easier to do this by inserting/updating/deleting rows in a table than it is to change alter your view.

Instead it would be better to create a [junction table (Associative entity)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=161310727e53dfac34683ee59de3d1e7):

```
CREATE TABLE ABMapping 
(   
    AID INT NOT NULL, 
    BID INT NOT NULL
); 
INSERT INTO ABMapping (AID, BID) 
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3);
```

Then you can join to this in your view:

```
CREATE VIEW GoodWay
AS
SELECT  map.AID, a.Name AS AName, map.BID, b.Name AS BName
FROM    TableA AS a
        INNER JOIN ABMapping AS map
            ON map.AID = a.ID
        INNER JOIN TableB AS b
            ON b.ID = map.BID;
```

**[Examples on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78831d90accd6016ef94e8008d9e3f80)**